# authentication, cant go through login page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

im trying create backend under password from database and i cant go through login page :P

**My AdminController**

```
class Backend::AdminController < ApplicationController

    layout :layout
    before_filter :authorize, :except => :login

    def authorize
        if session[:backend] != true
            redirect_to backend_login_path
        end
    end

    private
    def layout
        if session[:backend] == true
            "admin"
        else
            "login"
        end
    end

    def login
        employee = Employee.authenticate(params[:name], params[:password])
        if employee
            session[:backend] = true
            redirect_to backend_root_path, :notice => "Logged in!"
        else
            flash.now.alert = "Invalid login"
        end
    end

    def logout
        session[:backend] = nil
        redirect_to backend_login_path, :notice => "Logged out!"
    end

end
```

**My Routes**

```
match "backend/login" => "backend/admin#login"
match "backend/logout" => "backend/admin#logout"
```

**My Login page**

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
<% end %>   
<h1>Log in</h1>

<%= form_tag backend_login_path do %>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag :name %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag :name, params[:name] %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag :password %><br />
    <%= password_field_tag :password %>
  </p>
  <p class="button"><%= submit_tag "Log in" %></p>
<% end %>
```

when i go on url /backend im redirected to /backend/login, thats right
when i enter good login or bad login nothing happened and NO flashes appears thats strange ?
from webserver console output, i see the POST informations go through login method.. i dont know what is wrong ? thank you

edit: when i try go to URL /backend/logout im getting

```
Unknown action

    The action 'logout' could not be found for Backend::AdminController
```

i really dont understand this :( im begginer

Comment: private methods cant be actions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of the conventions in rails is, that public methods in a controller are considered to be actions.

if you want to write methods for before_filter etc, make them `private` or `protected` so that rails will not expose them as actions.

on the flipside, you are not able to define actions as `private`.